# How to create table according to current date in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

How to create the following data table in bigquery?

1. The table was created by integration tool (`google analytics to bigquery`)
2. The table will created each date: `events_intraday_date`
   [image]

I've tried to create table with partitioned, however there are different type.

How can I create the sub table in each day.

Comment: Does this [link](https://www.cloudskillsboost.google/focuses/3694?parent=catalog) help you in resolving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Those are not partitions, just a set of tables that shares a name prefix and have the same schema.

So you can just create your tables following the pattern `events_intraday_YYYYMMDD` and BigQuery will allow to query all tables at once using the wildcard notation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables